# Integrate Facebook Messenger into Unity

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, messenger

How integrate sharing via Facebook Messenger in Unity game. I have olready try to use Facebook Unity SDK 6.2.2 and 7.0.2 beta. Does Facebook SDK support it?

Comment: you can easily find answer by looking in Facebook sdk Documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible at the current time via the Unity SDK. Right now there is no support for the [Messenger SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger) as it is only available for Android and iOS.

In the current versions of the Facebook Unity SDK the only options you have for sharing/sending requests are the [FB.Feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Feed) and [FB.AppRequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.AppRequest) methods.